# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Create functional index

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a functional index (with the PostgreSQL function lower()). I get this error when using Alembic to create the table:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "lower" does not exist
 'CREATE INDEX ix_cities_name ON cities (lower)' {}
```

Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class City(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'

    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

db.Index('ix_cities_name', db.func.lower(db.metadata.tables['cities'].c.name))
```

Comment: According to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/constraints.html#functional-indexes it should work, but I get the above error.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

db.Index('ix_cities_name', func.lower(City.name))
```

reference to:

```
Functional indexes are supported as well, typically by using the
:data:`.func` construct in conjunction with table-bound
:class:`.Column` objects::

    Index("some_index", func.lower(sometable.c.name))
```

In addition, thank you for this question, I know how to create the index!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately alembic can't generate correct revision for functional indexes yet (I hope). You migration should be looks like:

```
op.execute("CREATE INDEX ix_cities_name ON cities (LOWER(name))")
```